# How to close all collapsible divs when modal is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is simple but after looking at the respective APIs, I don't know how to accomplish the following:

On my webpage, I have a [modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals). This modal contains an [accordion](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse) with several collapsible `div` elements. When I open the modal, open some collapsibles in the accordion, close the modal and open the modal again, the opened collapsibles are still open. I'd rather want all open collapsibles to be closed when the modal gets closed. How do I do that?

Or, to simplify my problem even further, how can I generally close all open collapsibles in an accordion at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `accordion-body` class name for your accordion body sections as per the example you link, and your modal has id `myModal` as per your other example, then:

```
$("#myModal").on("hidden", function() {
    $("#myModal .accordion-body").collapse("hide");
});
```

will collapse the modal's accordion sections each time the modal is hidden.

Comment: Oh dear, the solution apparently is as simple as the problem. Now I got it. Thank you very much. :)